# Can the spell legendary proportions be cast on a PC?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, targeting

The spell [*legendary proportions*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/legendary-proportions/) says that it can only target creatures. What, exactly, counts as a creature? Are PCs creatures? Are all living things creatures? Or are creatures only nonsentient things like horses?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Anything that has a Wisdom and Charisma score is a creature. Anything that lacks them is an object.

That means not only any living being, but also a bunch of non-living ones; Undead are creatures, as are Constructs and Elementals.

So yes, you can use such spells on players, other humanoids, animals, etc. The spell specifically calls out that it doesn't work on Undead though; which shows that Undead are normally also considered creatures, just this spell won't work on them.

(Note that a *lot* of spells target creatures, many of which you'd expect to be able to use on just about anything. Magic Missile for example also targets creatures, you would not expect it to only work on animals, right?)

---

Quoting from the [SRD on abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores/):

Under Wisdom:

> Every creature has a Wisdom score.

Under Charisma:

> Every creature has a Charisma score.

In the notes for both:

> Regular plants, such as one finds growing in gardens and fields, lack Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores; even though plants are alive, they are objects, not creatures.

It's spelled out even more literally in the D&D 3.5e SRD on [Wisdom](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Wisdom) (& the same for Charisma):

> Any creature that can perceive its environment in any fashion has at least 1 point of Wisdom. Anything with no Wisdom score is an object, not a creature. Anything without a Wisdom score also has no Charisma score.

Comment: "Anything that lacks them is an object" -> do you have rule support for that? Anyway in practice it seems to be the case.

Comment: I would also like something that specifies that Wisdom and Charisma are what make a 'creature'. Is there an object that is provided with Strength, Dexterity, Constitution, and Intelligence stats? By this reasoning, Intelligent items are creatures... is that also true?

Comment: @AnneAunyme I have added references to the SRD for it.

Comment: @Ifusaso indeed according to these rules an intelligent item would be a creature. (If it has cha/wis, but most do)

Comment: @Ifusaso The *3.5* revision failed to update intelligent items so as to make them more creatureish, so in *Pathfinder* intelligent items remain in this terrible place between being *like* creatures but not *really, really* creatures—for instance, intelligent items have no feats, skill ranks, or a base attack bonus (unless through item powers). Also, an *inverse* isn't always true: anything with *no* Wisdom score is an object and not a creature, but anything *with* a Wisdom score is *not* therefore necessarily a creature and *not* an object! (I *know!* How terrible is *that*, huh?)

Comment: @Eric "[Intelligent magic items possess all three mental ability scores: Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/intelligent-items/#TOC-Intelligent-Item-Ability-Scores)"

Comment: Your clarifications are good enough that, if I don't think it was their intent, still pretty clearly lay out a rule to use for deciding if something is a Creature. Good work, for sure.

Comment: I agree with @HeyICanChan that "all creatures have Wis and Cha" is not the same thing as "anything that has Wis and Cha is a creature". All dogs have fur, but not all things that have fur are dogs. The SRD states that every creature has a type; most magical objects wouldn't qualify for anything in the list of creature types, even if they had Wis and Cha, which implies that they're not creatures.